Export cloudwatch logs to S3 bucket
I was following this document to export the logs to S3 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3ExportTasks.html#ExportCrossAccount-CLI
I am doing it for the cross accounts,
Here is S3 bucket permissions
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "logs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::cloudwatch-exportlogs1",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceAccount": "477912222803"
                },
                "ArnLike": {
                    "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:477912222803:log-group:/aws/lambda/applicationLambda:*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "logs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::cloudwatch-exportlogs1/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control",
                    "aws:SourceAccount": "477912222803"
                },
                "ArnLike": {
                    "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:477912222803:log-group:/aws/lambda/applicationLambda:*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::477912222803:role/CloudWatchLogsExportToS3"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::cloudwatch-exportlogs1/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

Source IAM role and Policy attached
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "logs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::DESTINATIONID:role/<rolename>"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateExportTask",
                "logs:DescribeExportTasks",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:CancelExportTask"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

Destination IAM role and Policy attached
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<Source ID>:role/<role_name>"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "logs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateExportTask",
                "logs:CancelExportTask",
                "logs:DescribeExportTasks",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::cloudwatch-exportlogs1",
                "arn:aws:s3:::cloudwatch-exportlogs1/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

I am getting this error "An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the CreateExportTask operation: Please ensure that the export role and the destination bucket have all the required permissions as per the documentation."
AM I using the correct permissions?
aws logs create-export-task --task-name "my-log-group-09-23-2024" --log-group-name "/aws/lambda/applicationLambda" --from 1727046409000 --to 1727129846000 --destination "cloudwatch-exportlogs1" --destination-prefix "export-task-output" --region us-west-2


Just checking... Did you replace arn:aws:iam::DESTINATIONID:role/<rolename> and arn:aws:iam::<Source ID>:role/<role_name> with actual values?

In the linked documentation I couldn't see any mention of creating a destination role, so they probably aren't required. It looks like it basically needs a Bucket Policy on the Destination Bucket that permits access from an IAM Role from the source account.
